# how to fixed this Error 404 The system is unable to find the requested action "index"

Tags: php, yii

when i called controller then show Error 404 The system is unable to find the requested action "index".

its Test controller file

```
class TestController extends Controller

{
   public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new SignupForm();
    if(isset($_POST['SignupForm']))
   {
       // collects user input data
        $model->attributes=$_POST['SignupForm'];
        // validates user input and redirect to previous page if validated
        if($model->validate())
           $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
   }
    // displays the login form
    $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model));
}
  }
```

Its model File

```
class SignupForm extends CFormModel
  {

    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe=false;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('username, password', 'required'),
            array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
            array('password', 'authenticate'),
        );
    }

    public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        if(!$this->_identity->authenticate())
            $this->addError('password','Incorrect username or password.');
    }

  }
```

When i called controller then show Error 404 The system is unable to find the requested action "index" so how to fixed this error

Comment: call `test/login` instead of `test/` which would call the default action `index`

Comment: Or define default action `public $defaultAction = 'test';` in your controller. Can also be defined in `init()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action "index" is the default action in Yii controllers. You can change this behavior, setting you default index of a particular controller.

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public $defaultAction = 'login';

    public function actionLogin()
    {
    }
}
```

In this case, when you run /index.php?r=test will be like /index.php?r=test/login.

Answer (score 0):

There is no actionIndex() method in your controller. So either call www.yourwebsite.com/index.php?r=test/login or create an actionIndex() method in your test controller.